# How to pass selected (bootstrap card from homeComponent) to another component (favourtiesComponent) in angular 6?

Tags: arrays, angular, multidimensional-array

**EXAMPLE:** When clicked on the Title of the Book(A Monk who sold his ferrari..), i want to pass the Selected One to the Favorites component.. by default it's adding all items in an array.

*HomeComponent:* (How to add single item on click than adding all items to the favourtiesComponent?)

[image]

*FavourtiesComponent:*

[image]

**App Module**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormInputComponent } from './form-input/form-input.component';
import { MyBookService } from './mybook.service';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { FavsComponent } from './favs/favs.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { FavouriteService } from './favs.service';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'favourites', component: FavsComponent},
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FormInputComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FavsComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  providers: [MyBookService, FavouriteService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**HomeComponent.html**

```
  <!-- loading form -->
  <app-form-input></app-form-input>

  <!-- output -->
  <div class="card text-white bg-dark" style="max-width: 18rem;"
  *ngFor="let book of myBooks">
      <div class="card-header" (click)="onAdd()"> {{ book.title }} </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <!-- <h5 class="card-title">Dark card title</h5> -->
        <p class="card-text"> {{ book.content }} </p>
      </div>
  </div>
```

**HomeComponent.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { MyBookService } from '../mybook.service';
import { Book } from '../book.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  myBooks: Book[];

  constructor(private bookService: MyBookService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myBooks = this.bookService.getBooks(); // Loading books

    // Listening to changes
    this.bookService.booksChanged
      .subscribe(
        (book: Book[]) => {
          this.myBooks = book;
        }
      );
  }

  onAdd() {
    this.bookService.addedBooks(this.myBooks);
  }
}
```

**MyBookService.ts**

```
import { Book } from './book.model';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { FavouriteService } from './favs.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Favourites } from './favs/fav.model';

@Injectable()
export class MyBookService {

  booksChanged = new Subject<Book[]>();
  bookSelected = new Subject<Book>();

  constructor(private favService: FavouriteService) {}

  private myBooks: Book[] = [
    new Book('A Monk who sold his ferrari', 'A burning sense of passion is the most potent fuel for your dreams.'),
    new Book('The Secret', 'You are already incredibly blessed, you just haven’t noticed.')
  ];

  getBooks() {
    return this.myBooks.slice();
  }

  addBooks(book: Book) {
    this.myBooks.push(book);
    this.booksChanged.next(this.myBooks.slice());
  }

  addedBooks(favBook: Favourites[]) {
    this.favService.addedFavBooks(favBook);
    console.log('favBook: ', favBook);
  }

}
```

**FavourtiesService:**

```
  private favBooks: Favourites[] = [
  ];

  getFavbooks() {
    return this.favBooks.slice();
  }

  addedFavBooks(favBooks: Favourites[]) {
    this.favBooks.push(...favBooks);
    this.favBooksChanged.next(this.favBooks.slice());
  }
}
```

**FavouriteComponent.html**

```
<div class="container mt-3"> 
  <h3 class="mb-3">My Favourties: </h3>
</div>

<!-- output -->
  <div class="card text-white bg-dark" style="max-width: 18rem;"
  *ngFor="let favBook of favBooks">
      <div class="card-header"> {{ favBook.title }} </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text"> {{ favBook.content }} </p>
      </div>
  </div>
```

**FavouritesComponent.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FavouriteService } from '../favs.service';
import { Favourites } from './fav.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-favs',
  templateUrl: './favs.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./favs.component.css']
})
export class FavsComponent implements OnInit {
  favBooks: Favourites[];
  favBook: Favourites;

  constructor(private favService: FavouriteService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // this.myBooks = this.bookService.addedBooks(); // Loading books
    this.favBooks = this.favService.getFavbooks();

    this.favService.favBooksChanged
      .subscribe(
        (favs: Favourites[]) => {
          this.favBooks = favs;
        }
      );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a book is selected, add only that book to service. To do that, from HTML you can pass currently selected book to component.ts as given below.

After the modifications, The code might look like this.

HomeComponent.html

```
  <!-- loading form -->
  <app-form-input></app-form-input>

  <!-- output -->
  <div class="card text-white bg-dark" style="max-width: 18rem;"
  *ngFor="let book of myBooks">
      <div class="card-header" (click)="onAdd(book)"> {{ book.title }} </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <!-- <h5 class="card-title">Dark card title</h5> -->
        <p class="card-text"> {{ book.content }} </p>
      </div>
  </div>
```

HomeComponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { MyBookService } from '../mybook.service';
import { Book } from '../book.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  myBooks: Book[];

  constructor(private bookService: MyBookService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myBooks = this.bookService.getBooks(); // Loading books

    // Listening to changes
    this.bookService.booksChanged
      .subscribe(
        (book: Book[]) => {
          this.myBooks = book;
        }
      );
  }

  onAdd(selectedBook) {
    this.bookService.addedBooks([selectedBook]);
  }
}
```